# How to get the last element within several elements?

Tags: jquery

If I have the following HTML:

```
 <div>
  <span></span>
  <span>I want this one</span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span></span>
  <span>I want this one</span>
 </div>
```

How can I get the last two spans?

If I do this `$('div').find('span:last')` or `$('div').find('span').last()` then I only get the last one?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: You're looking for the last-child, not the last element

Comment: `$('div').find('span:last')` works but not `$('div').find('span').last()`  see: http://jsfiddle.net/S298c/

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was a simplified example.

Comment: @JoeNFU that's what i was thinking, not relevant markup posted ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("div span:last-child")
```

will return an array though ! with all matches , so better use `.each()`

```
 $("div span:last-child").each(function( index ) {
  //your actions
});
```

Comment: Ah, I should have thought of that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Working example is here
http://jsfiddle.net/S298c/9/

```
$('div').each(function(){
   var lastspantext = $(this).find('span:last-child').html();
   alert(lastspantext);
});
```